# How to find which all folders in gcp bucket contain a file with particular name using java api

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform

I have a Google cloud storage bucket with following structure
Gs://myBucket/folder1/1.txt
Gs://myBucket/folder2/1.txt
Gs://myBucket/folder3/3.txt

I wish to know using Java api which all folders contain file with name 1.txt.
in my above example it will be folder1 and folder2

Answer (score 1):

Folders aren't a resource in Google Cloud Storage (GCS), see [Folders](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/folders).

The only resource that Buckets may contain are Objects.

There isn't a Folder resource in GCS Buckets that you can grab a handle to and which contains File things.

Object names permit "/" and **many tools manifest this as if it were a directory path separator** (but it really isn't).

You will need to iterate over **every** object (see: [List](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects#storage-list-objects-java) and pattern-match on every Object name ending e.g. `1.txt`.

Comment: Isnt there a way in java APIs like we have in cloud shell : gsutil ls gs://myBucket/*/1.txt

Comment: Possibly. With `gcloud` you can add `--log-http` to see the underlying REST calls, do you know if there's an equivalent with `gsutil`? That may highlight how it achieves it.

Comment: Looks like you can use `-D` with `gsutil` to get HTTP details